# Comment vote limit warning text on beta Stack Exchange sites is hard to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, user-interface, comment-voting

On the beta Stack Exchange sites, the "click on this box to dismiss" is white on yellow and in my opinion is hard to read.

[image: comment vote limit warning]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I thought I had fixed this but apparently it's still happening. I put in a new fix and it will be in the next production build.